# Chrome browser not allowing iframe source to load for Webchat url

Tags: google-chrome, botframework

I have registered a bot and was working fine till yesterday. All of a sudden my chrome browser refused to load my webchat control of MS Botframework. When i checked the console it throws me the following policies are restricting the iframe from loading url. I tried adding meta-tags but didn't helped me.

```
Refused to frame 'https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/DiPA_BOT?s=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' *.mydomain.com". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Also this

```
botchat.js:34449 Refused to connect to 'https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' *.accenture.com". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code in the html doc for me? While you are at it, you say chrome doesn't load the iframe. Does this mean other browsers work fine? If so right click the refresh icon used to reload a page and clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue why chrome is refused to frame/load directline call and am posting here, may it help for someone like me.

In my server iis,In Http headers section, i saw a header as [Conten-Security-Policy](https://content-security-policy.com/). After disabled it, my Bot calls works fine.